# Div Children Not Listening to CSS When Position Absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place text behind an image and have it so that when I hover, the image disappears and only the text behind it is visible. But I came across a problem where the text isn't listening to the div because all the child divs are set to position absolute. What alternative solutions are there?

```
.card {
  display:block;
  width:255;
  height:319;
  border-radius:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.card * { position:absolute; } //issue here code makes text come out of div card itself
.card img:hover { opacity:0; }

<div class='card'>
  <p>Title</p><p>2016</p>
  <p>Description , lots of image description</p>
  <img src="./img/image1.jpg" width="225" height="319">
</div>
```

Comment: A little more info might be helpful, maybe a jsfiddle. But from what I gather from your code the text leaving the div because the .card is not using "position:relative;". Assigning .card position:relative will keep the text within the the div. After that, maybe playing with z-index will get the text to go beneath the image.

Comment: Yeah, that does fix that thanks, now just the text sitting on top of each other is the only problem , thanks again!

Comment: No problem! For the sake of the question I'll put this in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign:

```
position:relative;
```

to .card to keep the text within the div.

Comment: It actually dosen't work still ... Sorry I had set a class to the text itself and made the width ... relative to what though?

Comment: Well, the width of the text shouldn't matter. If .card has position:relative then any element within it with position:absolute will remain inside of it. Do you have a jsfiddle or other example of the problem that might shed more light on it?